# How can I get quantity of numbers in array which are in some range?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

I have this array filled by numbers:

```
Image<Gray, Byte> imgHue = channels[0];
```

I need somehow to get quantity of the number in array that are in the range of 100-105.

Any idea how to implement it?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Googling, I think your `channels` variable may be of type `Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Gray, byte>[]`. Is this the "array filled by numbers" you're talking about? Then, which number needs to be in the range 100-105?

Answer (score 5):

```
someArray.Count(x => x >= 100 && x <= 105)
```

Comment: Image<Gray, Byte> dosent have Count extension

Comment: Then why doe the word "array" occur so much in your post?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type is `Image` *Value* (second parameter), **if** it's `IEnumerable<Byte>`, you can do:

```
var rangeofBytes = imgHue.Values.Count(b => b >= 100 && b <= 105)
```

Comment: Maybe change the name from *byte* to something that's not reserved in C#?

Comment: Don't know how sensible it is to use a primitive type name as a parameter name